# Hacer una variable no reseateable

Tags: javascript

Cuando llamaste a una función y esta tiene variables declaradas dentro y vuelves a llamar a la función, como por ejemplo en una función recursiva, las variables dentro se vuelven a declarar, y mi problema es,

¿Cómo puedo hacer que una variable NO se reinicie?
, con esto me refiero a que no pierda su último valor cuando se vuelva a llamar a la misma función.

Ejemplo:

```js
function callMe(n){
 var arr = [];
 if(arr.length < 4) {
 arr.push(n);
 callMe(n*2);
 }
 else {
 return 0;
 }
}

console.log(callMe(2));
```

Ya que la variable `arr`, siempre se vuelve a definir, se provoca un bucle infinito.

Sé que puede hacerse pasandole el array como parámetro, pero ese no es el enfoque de mi pregunta, sino de cómo hacer para que una variable no pierda su último valor.

Comment: Has probado usando declarando la variable como parte de la función. `this.array`?

Comment: No conozco ese método Jose, y Mariano escribí de hecho que eso es lo que ya sé hacer.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian perdón, me pase de largo la última línea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción es crear un objeto:

```js
var obj={
  arr: [],
  callMe: function (n) {
    if(this.arr.length < 4) {
      this.arr.push(n);
      this.callMe(n*2);
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

obj.callMe(2);
console.log(obj.arr);
```

Pero en el caso de las funciones recursivas, lo ideal es que pases como parámetro la variable, devolviéndola como resultado:

```js
//La segunda variable es opcional, si no la pasamos se asume un array vacío
function callMe(n,arr=[]) {

  if(arr.length < 4) {
      arr.push(n);
      //caso recursivo, devolvemos el resultado de la llamada
      return callMe(n*2,arr); 
  } else {
      return arr; //caso base, el array tiene ya 4 elementos
  }
}
  
  console.log(callMe(2));
```

Answer (score 4):

Debes declarar la variable `arr` fuera del ámbito de la función.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo. La función que se ejecuta es la función anónima interna que devuelve al ejecutarse la primera que sirve para definir un ámbito para la variable y la función que la utilizará:

```js
var callMe = function(){
  var arr = [];
  return function(n){
    if (arr.length < 4){
      arr.push(n);
      callMe(n*2);
      return arr;
    }
    else{
      return 0;
    }
  };
}();


console.log(callMe(2));
```